# Why bower packages lag behind production releases?

Tags: yeoman, bower

I noticed that when I use `yo webapp` to make a new web application, it's still using jQuery 1.10.2 even though 1.11.0 is out. Is it because 1.11.0 is not heavily tested yet, so the bower repository is still using 1.10.2?  If I keep running `bower update` once in a while, will jQuery (and any other packages I'm using) eventually upgrade? (I do realize, BTW, that I can force it with `bower install jquery#1.11.0 -S`)

Related question: This is my current bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "wut",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "sass-bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

When I run `bower update`, sass-bootstrap is not updated to the latest available (3.0.2). Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version is [semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver) and `~1.10.2` means any patch  version (`major.minor.patch`) higher than 2, but less than `1.11.0`. You need to bump up the version in your bower.json to `~1.11.0` to get the `1.11.0` version.